# User aunthentication not working for connecting IBM MQ

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq, jndi

I have following xml configuration connecting IBM MQ but its not checking username I have provided.

```
<bean id="mq01" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfiguratione0l" />
</bean>

‹bean id="jmsConfiguration01" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="credentialsConnectionFactory01"/›
    <property name="username" value="userid" /> 
    <property name="password" value="userid" /›
    ‹property name="testConnectionOnStartup" value="true" /> 
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
</bean>

‹bean id="credentialsConnectionFactory01" class="org.springframework-jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property nane="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jndiFactoryBean01" /> 
    <property name="username" value="userid" /> 
    <property name="password" value="userid" />
</bean>

<bean id="jndiFactoryBean01" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate01"/› 
    <property name="jndiName" value="mq1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jndiTemplate01" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment"
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial"›com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</prop> 
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${binding.url}</props 
            <prop key="java.naming.security.authentication">simple</prop> 
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">userid</prop> 
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">userid</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Its throwing below error:

IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').

Comment: You need to see what the queue manger's AMQERR01.LOG says to know the cause of the 2035.

Comment: This is what we see in queue manager logs: The inbound channel '*****' was blocked from address '********' because the active values of the channel matched a record configured with USERSRC (NOACCESS)

Comment: That error message means that a CHLAUTH rule has blocked you. Without knowing your qmgr configuration, we might guess that this is the default rule that disallows remote applications trying to assert privileged authorities. Are you asserting an mqm user id?

Comment: btw - do you have a typo here (first line): org.apache.comel.component.jms.JmsComponent - should comel be camel?

Comment: Yes it was typo. And queue manager has configured to allow access to 'userid' only. but my configuration is not passing username with it.

Comment: How is CONNAUTH configured on your queue manager?   What error do you see in the AMQERR01.LOG  just before the channel blocked error?

Comment: queue manager configuration is correct. I am not able to pass username with this configuration

Comment: If you know that it is correct then why post a question on here?

Comment: There was issue with dependency version which were not  passing username